# Bootstrap 4.2 - Modal - Input fields not editable, button not clickable, not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
[image]

I have bootstrap 4.2.1 modal opening via link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteByEmailPopup" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false">Add by Email</a>
```

the modal div at the end, right at the closing body tag

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="inviteByEmailPopup"  aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" data-backdrop="false">
        <div class="card bg-transparent border-white mt-5">
            <div class="card-header brand-gradient border-white">
                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="text-white text-uppercase">Invite By Email</h5>

            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-3 pb-5 bg-brand-grey">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="text-white col-md-12" for="usern1">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="inviteName" class="name-input form-control" type="text"  >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      ~~~ Truncated for brevity only one input kept for example ~~~~
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I have tried:**

1. moving modal around to avoid any "fixed" content overlay.
2. Playing with z-index, setting modal to higher z-index than backdrop.
3. I followed this guide: (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/14/bootstrap-modal-dialog-showing-under-modal-background) even though it's from 2016
4. I disabled backdrop with `data-backdrop="false"` and in my main CSS.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    /* bug fix - no overlay */
    display: none;
}
```

5. I installed z-index plugin for Chrome to debug this issue. Z-indexes are correct.
6. I've scouted entire stack overflow, and tried every accepted and unaccepted answer here. This isn't the first day I am working with Bootstrap and very versed in css/html. This is driving me insane.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: Why are you using card classes for a modal exactly? I've looked through some examples in the bootstrap doc and none of them use the card class.

Comment: @Vins, those are just styled themed classes. Removing them had no effect. Original developer created those styles.

Comment: Can you see if the pointer-events property has been altered in anyway?
It might not be on the modal itself, sometimes its on the backdrop element and the modal inherits it

Comment: @Vins  I am starting to suspect that bootstrap modal does not work unless it has modal-content class.... because, default, plain old modal from bootstrap example works.  I just added modal content div to my original box and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add modal-content class to your modal:

Add by Email

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="inviteByEmailPopup">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"  style="background-color: #404041;" >
      <div class="modal-header brand-gradient border-white">
        <div class="brand-gradient border-white">
          <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h5 class="text-white text-uppercase">Invite By Email</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body p-3 pb-5 bg-brand-grey">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="text-white col-md-12" for="usern1">Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="inviteName" class="name-input form-control" type="text"  >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          ~~~ Truncated for brevity only one input kept for example ~~~~
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Had the same issue and search high and low through every z-index and positioning bug I could think of. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved in process of troubleshooting thanks to the comments.

First, Bootstrap modal, REQUIRES that you have `<div class="modal-content">...</div>` inside your modal to wrap your content. Without it, z-index and focus all out of whack.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @TrueStory can you please point me what so special in modal-content css class its starts working. That will be helpful in further debugging the cause